# why do we have unshared objects in fligweight?

Tags: design-patterns, flyweight-pattern

why do we have both shared and unshared objects inside fligweight pool? the purpose of flighweight is to share some objects between other objects,so why do we want to have unshared objects?

the gof also said about this that I dont understand it :

> UnsharedConcreteFlyweight: not all Flyweight subclasses need to be
> shared. The Flyweight interface enables sharing; it doesn't enforce
> it. It's common for UnsharedConcreteFlyweight objects to have
> ConcreteFlyweight objects as children at some level in the flyweight
> object structure.

picture from Gof that used unshared objects:
[image]

Comment: There seems to be a pretty good answer here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/333416/flyweight-pattern-unsharedconcreteflyweight